# How to hide buses from Google Map object?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there anywhere in the Google Map API to hide the buses from the map? I could not find anything in the mapOptions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Related: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#TransitLayer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can apply styles in the mapOptions:

```
var mapOptions = {
        styles: [
          {
            featureType: "transit.station.bus",
            stylers: [
              { visibility: "off" }
            ]
          }
        ]};
        map.setOptions(mapOptions);
```

See the [**styling wizard**](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html) for more.